# How to migrate from Microsoft SQL server database (on local machine) to LocalDB?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, web-applications, sql-server-2008-r2, localdb

I have a simple web application that accesses tables in the Microsoft SQL server database installed locally on my laptop. But in order to run the application on every other laptop I have to migrate to localDB. Please suggest.!

Comment: Does your application need to access data that you have centrally, or does it just need to store data for each user?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is an obvious/dumb answer:  The great value of web applications is that they can be accessed remotely by users who don't have to install anything to use them.  Install your database and web application on a server and you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: No But this is for academic project purposes. so the purpose is simple. I create the application and hand it over to some other group of people so that they perform testing. They can run it via localhost and test it. but inorder to do that I have to migrate to local DB. Hope you understand.